# References to objects. Why does this variable change?

Tags: python

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Test():
def __init__(self):
    self.myList = [i for i in range(10)]

def method(self, val, num):
    for i in range(10):
        if i < val:
            self.myList[i] = num

inst = Test()

before = inst.myList
print 'before = ', before
inst.method(4, 6)
print 'after = ', inst.myList
print ' '

inst.myList = before
print 'before = ', before
inst.method(2, 4)
print 'before = ', before
print 'after = ', inst.myList`
```

Gives the output of:

```
before =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
after =  [6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

before =  [6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
before =  [4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
after =  [4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why does the before variable change after the second call to method()? Something about references to objects? Is it because inst.myList = before makes them both point to the same list, so when I change inst.myList, before also changes?

Also, if i call method with something like:

```
inst.method(2, 4)
```

Is this guaranteed to change inst.myList for later use in the program if it is changed in the method? Or do I need to do something like this in the Test class?

```
@staticmethod
def method(listtt, val, num):
    # do stuff to list
    return listtt
```

and then call it with:

```
inst.myList = Test.method(inst.myList, 2, 4)
```

I do not fully understand the pass by assignment stuff and what is and isn't mutable yet. If it is the second one, then what is the point of using self at all if I have to pass everything in and return everything anyways? Why not just have all static methods?

Comment: I don't really understand the last part of your question.  What do you mean by "guaranteed to change `inst.myList` for later use"?  What are you trying to accomplish with your staticmethod.

Comment: *Variables* do not change unless the are reassigned; however, the *objects* to which a variable refers changes if it was changed anywhere (because, uhh, it was changed).

Comment: You need to add proper indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because inst.myList = before makes them both point to the same list, so when I change inst.myList, before also changes?

Yes, that is exactly why.

As for whether `inst.method` is "guaranteed" to change `inst.myList`, that depends what you mean.  With the particular implementation you gave, yes, it is guaranteed to change it as long as it is a list, because you used item assignment (the `foo[bar] = baz` syntax), and that syntax mutates lists.  But of course you could write `inst.method` a different way so it doesn't modify `inst.myList`, so in that sense it's not "guaranteed".